# ADB Device not authorized in Recovery Mode. How to get authorized?

Tags: android, adb

I'm on Arch Linux.
I want to ADB into my DOOGEE DG800 ... via recovery mode.

It gets listed at »adb devices« but it is "unauthorized".
So why is authorization check enabled in recovery? Or is this recovery already when the chinese menu appears?

Is it possible to flash a custom recovery without loosing data from the phone system?

How to get authorized?

Comment: Did you find something about this?